# Java EWS findappointments dates acting weird, either returns to much or nothing

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I'm not sure how the `start` and `end date` work with the whole find appointments.  I am getting all the rooms for a public group, then getting the rooms for the group, then getting the appointments within a date range.

But the ranges act weird, I know there are appointments on `12-19` to `12-16`, but if I set the start date range to `2013-10-10` and the end date to `2013-12-28`, I get nothing.

If I set the end date to `2014-01-28`, I get tons of stuff that is in the range previously mentioned.  Why is that?

```
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials( "username", "pw");
    service.setCredentials( credentials );    
    service.setUrl( new URI("my mail url") );
    Folder inbox = Folder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
    System.out.println("messages: " + inbox.getTotalCount());
    CalendarFolder cf = CalendarFolder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);

//Get all new appts?

java.text.SimpleDateFormat formatter= new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-mm-dd");
Date startDate1 = formatter.parse("2013-11-25");
Date endDate1 = formatter.parse("2014-01-28 ");



EmailAddressCollection myRoomLists = service.getRoomLists();
for (EmailAddress item : myRoomLists)
{
    System.out.println("Room Email========"+ item.toString());

    NameResolutionCollection nameResolutions = service.resolveName(
        item.getName(),
        ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly,
        true);

        for (NameResolution nameResolution : nameResolutions)

        {
            ExpandGroupResults groupResults;
            //System.out.println(nameResolution.getMailbox().getAddress());
            try {            
                groupResults = service.expandGroup(nameResolution.getMailbox().getAddress());
            } catch (microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceResponseException e){
                    groupResults=null;
                    System.out.println("NO INFO FOR "+nameResolution.getMailbox().getAddress());
            }           

            if (groupResults!=null){                          
                for (EmailAddress member : groupResults.getMembers())
                {

                        if (member.getAddress().indexOf("rm.Cary")>-1){

                            System.out.println(member.getName() + " <" + member.getAddress() + ">");
                            FolderId folderid = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(member.getAddress()));
                            try {            
                                FindItemsResults<Appointment> aps = service.findAppointments(folderid, new CalendarView(startDate1,endDate1));
                                for (Item items : aps.getItems())
                                {
                                    Appointment appt = (Appointment)items;
                                    System.out.println("SUBJECT===== " + appt.getSubject());
                                    System.out.println("Location======== " + appt.getLocation());
                                    System.out.println("Start Time========" + appt.getStart());
                                    System.out.println("End Time========"+appt.getEnd());
                                    System.out.println("Email Address========"+ appt.getOrganizer().getAddress());
                                    System.out.println("Last Modified Time========"+appt.getLastModifiedTime());
                                    System.out.println("Start time========"+appt.getStart());
                                    System.out.println("End Time========"+appt.getEnd());
                                    System.out.println("Is recurring========"+appt.getIsRecurring());
                                    System.out.println("Duration========"+appt.getDuration().toString());
                                    System.out.println("Organizer========"+appt.getOrganizer());
                                    System.out.println("Required Attendees========"+appt.getRequiredAttendees().getCount());
                                    System.out.println("Optional Attendees========"+appt.getOptionalAttendees().getCount());
                                        System.out.println(""); 

                                }

                            } catch (microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceResponseException e){
                                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                            }   


                        }
                    }
            }
        }

}

System.out.println("End");
```

Comment: ...code could be a little more neatly formatted

Comment: Yeah man, sorry about that.  Hope that is a little better!

Comment: check my edit, and please continue to format it in such style

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
java.text.SimpleDateFormat formatter= new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```